# How to define variable in controller in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a URL used in blade template as:

```
    href="{{ route('download', ['year' => $year, 'month' => $month, 'file' => $file_path]) }}"
```

when I am running my code then it is giving me an error as:

> Undefined variable: year (View: C:\wamp64\www\Blog\employee-portal\resources\views\finance\invoice\edit.blade.php)

How can i define this $year variable in my controller?

In my controller the function is written as:

```
    public function download($year, $month, $file, $inline = true)
    {
        $headers = [
            'content-type' => 'application/pdf',
        ];

        $file_path = FileHelper::getFilePath($year, $month, $file);

        if (!$file_path) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($inline) {
            return Response::make(Storage::get($file_path), 200, $headers);
        }

        return Storage::download($file_path);
    }
}
```

Edit function is written as:

```
    public function edit(Invoice $invoice)
    {
        $projectStageBillings = $invoice->projectStageBillings;

        $projectStageBilling = $projectStageBillings->first();
        $client = $projectStageBilling->projectStage->project->client;
        $client->load('projects', 'projects.stages', 'projects.stages.billings');

        $billings = [];
        foreach ($projectStageBillings as $key => $billing) {
            $billing->load('projectStage', 'projectStage.project');
            $billings[] = $billing;
        }

        return view('finance.invoice.edit')->with([
            'invoice' => $invoice,
            'clients' => Client::select('id', 'name')->get(),
            'invoice_client' => $client,
            'invoice_billings' => $billings,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Show your controller code.

Comment: above is the code

Comment: No shown in your code of the controller  where the edit page is returned

Comment: are you asking for the above code

Comment: Yes it is. In the edit function There is not any variable called `$year`, `$month`,  `$file_path`. and you are trying to access the variable without being declared. That is why its causing error. Specify the value in the `edit function`

Comment: it again gives me the error as- Undefined variable: year

Comment: You have to specify all the variable that is declared in the edit blade

Comment: i have specified all the variables but it still giving me the same error

Comment: Where are you specified the variables? In your edit method there is not any variable called `$year`, `$month`, `$file_path`

Comment: you are using these( => $year  => $month => $file_path) variable in your view/blade file  . Did you pass these variable from controller to your blade file to use ? if yes then plz show that code

Comment: You've got a lot of unanswered questions open with nothing being marked as an answer. Try to close up some of those first.

Comment: share the route

Answer (score 0):

This error states that the view `finance\invoice\edit.blade.php` is missing the variable `$year`. And it is true, take a look at the return of your edit function:

```
return view('finance.invoice.edit')->with([
    'invoice' => $invoice,
    'clients' => Client::select('id', 'name')->get(),
    'invoice_client' => $client,
    'invoice_billings' => $billings,
]);
```

You are not sending any `$year` variable to the view here (the variables sent to the view are `invoice`,`clients`,`invoice_client` and `invoice_billings`.

To solve your problem, just send a $year variable to the view and you'll be ok :)